# generating thousands unique unpredictable serial numbers

Tags: php

Hi I want to generate thousands of unique unpredictable serials, so I wrote this function

```
function generate_serials($count){
    $serials = array();
    $token = '8uhf7+-=??/\/';

    for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
        $hash = sha1(md5( $token . ( time() + (432 * 1000) ) ));
        $serial = '';
        for($j = 0; $j < 12; $j++){
            if($j == 4 || $j == 8) $serial .= '-';
            $serial .= $hash[rand(0, 39)];
            if(in_array($serial, $serials)){
                $serial = '';
                $j = 0;
            }
        }
        $serials[] = $serial;
    }
    return $serials;
}
```

I have few problems about this approach.

1. I don't know why, but I don't trust this. (As I always think my solutions and I are stupid) is there any problem with this?
2. another problem is with performance that it takes about 20-30 seconds, Is it natural or I made a mess?

***UPDATE***

Oh sorry guys
the problem of performance was that the counter for inner loop was the same name as outer loop ..my mistake! :D

Comment: Just use http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: @Dunhamzzz did you read the big yellow note on the page that you linked?

Comment: It'd be more random than your function as it's based on microseconds, a lot faster too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is overcomplicated. It doesn't have to be that way. If you have OpenSSL installed look into [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php)

Alternatively you could use [`mt_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) and [`hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) like so:

```
$serial = hash('sha512', mt_rand());
```

However `mt_rand` does not generate cryptographically secure values so it may not be as unpredictable as you wish.

Comment: Not only overcomplicated but much of the overcomplicating does not add any security. It was right not to trust a homegrown solution like that.